# Index out of range error in Verilog, although the register is declared correctly

Tags: input, output, verilog

I am trying to learn Verilog and I have this simple code

```
module division (
    output reg [14:0] A,
    input [14:0] D);
    
    reg[4:0] i;

    always @(*) begin
    
        for (i = 14; i >= 0; i = i-1) begin
            
            A[0] = D[i];
            
        end
    end         
endmodule
```

This returns the error : `Index out of range for D.`. I have no idea why, since D is declared on that interval. Can you please help me?
I know the code might not make any sense, but I only included the relevant part to the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `i` as unsigned, so the expression `i >= 0` will always be true.
When `i` reaches 0, the next iteration is 5'b11111, which is out of range. You should declare `i` as an `integer` or add the `signed` keyword.